# C# Two nearly identical threads, big performance difference

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

I have a big multithreaded system in C#, and I realized that performance was very different between two threads. Now I have designed two nearly identical threads, where one performs 4-5 times faster (And it scales up linearly if you change the amount of loops they have to run).
And the difference? One clumsy condition surrounding the actual heavy code of one of them. It makes no sense to me, and I feel powerless in optimizing going forward, if such a minor detail can have such a huge impact. This was tested in Unity, and as such it could be that the result is different in other environments.

**ThreadA finish time: 2.8 seconds.
ThreadB finish time: 0.6 seconds.**

Mind you ThreadB is the one that has a condition (Which will evaluate to true instantly on first while iteration).
How can such a stupid addition to the code make the actual payload (The for loops and the number crunching) perform so much faster? Also, if I change the "delay" variable with a static "0.0" directly in the condition of ThreadB, it performs like ThreadA again. In other words: One single double, and whether it is a hardcoded value, or references a variable, makes a difference in performance of a factor of 4-5.

Never mind the actual algorithm, which is only there to make the computer crunch some numbers. I know I am comparing the same data again and again, that is besides the point.

I am no compilation nerd, and I have no way of probing how this differs in actual machine/assembler code. I just know that the difference is huge, and non sensical to me. What do I miss? I discovered this by accident, and in the future I may not have any way of knowing a given thread performs at 20% possible speed, and that one slight change could solve it.

Please. I need a nerd to make this going from pure magic to "Oh, that's why...! Now I know how to avoid it in the future...". I know compilation of C# is surrounded by layers of managed stuff, but there must be a logical reason. Right?

Here is some test code with some simple structs to support it. If anyone has the time to check if they get the same results as I, I would be happy.

```
using System.Threading;

public class ThreadTest
{
    Thread threadA;
    Thread threadB;

    bool runThreadA = false;
    bool runThreadB = false;

    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch;

    double elapsedTimeA = 0;
    double elapsedTimeB = 0;
    
    public ThreadTest()
    {
        stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        StartThreads();
    }

    public void StartThreads ()
    {
        stopWatch.Reset();
        stopWatch.Start();
        threadA = new Thread(ThreadA);
        threadB = new Thread(ThreadB);

        runThreadA = true;
        runThreadB = true;

        elapsedTimeA = 0;
        elapsedTimeB = 0;
        threadA.Start();
        threadB.Start();
    }

    void ThreadA ()
    {
        while (runThreadA)
        {
            
            runThreadA = false;
            double preTicks = stopWatch.ElapsedTicks;

            Line3Double lineA = new Line3Double(new Vector3DoublePrecision(10, 20, 30), new Vector3DoublePrecision(100, 140, 180));
            Line3Double lineB = new Line3Double(new Vector3DoublePrecision(-10, -20, -30), new Vector3DoublePrecision(-100, -140, -180));

            int lines = 1000;

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < lines; j++)
                {
                    double aStartX = lineA.startX;
                    double aStartY = lineA.startY;
                    double aStartZ = lineA.startZ;

                    double aEndX = lineA.endX;
                    double aEndY = lineA.endY;
                    double aEndZ = lineA.endZ;

                    double aDirX = lineA.dirX;
                    double aDirY = lineA.dirY;
                    double aDirZ = lineA.dirZ;

                    double aDotSelf = lineA.dotSelf;

                    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
                    {
                        for (int l = 0; l < lines; l++)
                        {
                            double wX = aStartX - lineB.startX;
                            double wY = aStartY - lineB.startY;
                            double wZ = aStartZ - lineB.startZ;

                            double b = aDirX * lineB.dirX + aDirY * lineB.dirY + aDirZ * lineB.dirZ;
                            double d = aDirX * wX + aDirY * wY + aDirZ * wZ;
                            double e = lineB.dirX * wX + lineB.dirY * wY + lineB.dirZ * wZ;

                            double D = aDotSelf * lineB.dotSelf - b * b;
                            double sc, tc;
                            if (D < 0.0000001)
                            {
                                sc = 0.0f;
                                tc = (b > lineB.dotSelf ? d / b : e / lineB.dotSelf);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sc = (b * e - lineB.dotSelf * d) / D;
                                tc = (aDotSelf * e - b * d) / D;
                            }

                            double shortestX = wX + (sc * aDirX) - (tc * lineB.dirX);
                            double shortestY = wY + (sc * aDirY) - (tc * lineB.dirY);
                            double shortestZ = wZ + (sc * aDirZ) - (tc * lineB.dirZ);

                            double distance = shortestX * shortestX + shortestY * shortestY + shortestZ * shortestZ;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            double postTicks = stopWatch.ElapsedTicks;
            double time = ((postTicks - preTicks) / System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.Frequency) * 1000;
            elapsedTimeA = time;
        }
    }

    void ThreadB()
    {
        long startTicks = stopWatch.ElapsedTicks;
        double delay = 0;

        while (runThreadB)
        {
            if ((double)(stopWatch.ElapsedTicks - startTicks) / System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.Frequency >= delay)
            {
                runThreadB = false;
                double preTicks = stopWatch.ElapsedTicks;

                Line3Double lineA = new Line3Double(new Vector3DoublePrecision(10, 20, 30), new Vector3DoublePrecision(100, 140, 180));
                Line3Double lineB = new Line3Double(new Vector3DoublePrecision(-10, -20, -30), new Vector3DoublePrecision(-100, -140, -180));

                int lines = 1000;

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < lines; j++)
                    {
                        double aStartX = lineA.startX;
                        double aStartY = lineA.startY;
                        double aStartZ = lineA.startZ;

                        double aEndX = lineA.endX;
                        double aEndY = lineA.endY;
                        double aEndZ = lineA.endZ;

                        double aDirX = lineA.dirX;
                        double aDirY = lineA.dirY;
                        double aDirZ = lineA.dirZ;

                        double aDotSelf = lineA.dotSelf;

                        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
                        {
                            for (int l = 0; l < lines; l++)
                            {
                                double wX = aStartX - lineB.startX;
                                double wY = aStartY - lineB.startY;
                                double wZ = aStartZ - lineB.startZ;

                                double b = aDirX * lineB.dirX + aDirY * lineB.dirY + aDirZ * lineB.dirZ;
                                double d = aDirX * wX + aDirY * wY + aDirZ * wZ;
                                double e = lineB.dirX * wX + lineB.dirY * wY + lineB.dirZ * wZ;

                                double D = aDotSelf * lineB.dotSelf - b * b;
                                double sc, tc;
                                if (D < 0.0000001)
                                {
                                    sc = 0.0f;
                                    tc = (b > lineB.dotSelf ? d / b : e / lineB.dotSelf);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    sc = (b * e - lineB.dotSelf * d) / D;
                                    tc = (aDotSelf * e - b * d) / D;
                                }

                                double shortestX = wX + (sc * aDirX) - (tc * lineB.dirX);
                                double shortestY = wY + (sc * aDirY) - (tc * lineB.dirY);
                                double shortestZ = wZ + (sc * aDirZ) - (tc * lineB.dirZ);

                                double distance = shortestX * shortestX + shortestY * shortestY + shortestZ * shortestZ;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                double postTicks = stopWatch.ElapsedTicks;
                double time = ((postTicks - preTicks) / System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.Frequency) * 1000;
                elapsedTimeB = time;
            }
        }
    }
}
public struct Vector3DoublePrecision
{
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;

    public Vector3DoublePrecision(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}

public struct Line3Double
{
    public double startX;
    public double startY;
    public double startZ;
    public double endX;
    public double endY;
    public double endZ;

    public double dirX;
    public double dirY;
    public double dirZ;

    public double dotSelf;

    public Line3Double(Vector3DoublePrecision start, Vector3DoublePrecision end)
    {
        startX = start.x;
        startY = start.y;
        startZ = start.z;

        endX = end.x;
        endY = end.y;
        endZ = end.z;

        dirX = end.x - start.x;
        dirY = end.y - start.y;
        dirZ = end.z - start.z;

        dotSelf = dirX * dirX + dirY * dirY + dirZ * dirZ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Henrik. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you minimalize the example please? There are too much going on in there. If you want to burn some CPU time, you could just add an empty  `for` loop from zero to a billion. Also you could add a comment inside the code, to indicate the exact line that causes the dramatic change in performance you observe.

Comment: This is not an appropriate way to measure performance since it may depend on scheduling. 1. Run only one operation at a time (no threads!). 2. Run a warmup-pass for each to reduce the effect of compilation. 3. Stopwatch is not guaranteed to be thread safe. 4. Run the code a fixed number of times so the total time is about a second. 5. If in doubt, use Benchmark.Net

Comment: I cannot repro that on .NET Framework. I would change the loop to run the method for N times and use a separate Stopwatch and warm things up. It might be that you are measuring first time init effects on the first thread.

Comment: I had this question in other fora as well, and nobody seemed to be able to reproduce. And so I had to really dive in to the "Unity" part of the setup. And after changing the scripting backend from Mono to IL2CPP I not only get way better overall performance results, the problem is also gone.
So I guess it was a problem with JIT compilation. 
Never changed stuff like that in Unity before, never had to or saw a need.
I do now, for sure... Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Please don't post an answer in the question. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: Never used this forum before, sorry. I have posted as an "answer" now :)

Comment: JonasH: I agree, this could probably have been measured a lot more precisely, but as we are talking times in the seconds (And differences of a factor of 4-5), this was felt very much directly in when they reported back their results, not so much on some numbers from the Stopwatch class.

Comment: Theodor: It is the same stuff going on in both examples. So it may be a little "much", but at least it's the same "much".
Also, doing some actual stuff may show parts of the problem, as the solution (JIT vs AOT compilation) really shows the difference, when floating arithmetic is invoked, not just some empty loops from 0 to a billion.

Comment: Alois: Nobody could, anywhere... Because it was a Unity setting problem. 
And I tried it on both threads separately (Ran them one at a time), same times reported. Thanks for your effort, though, and see the "Answer", if you want to know how it was solved. Still strange, though...

Comment: @HenrikKragh - Please use the `@` to get send the recipients a notification. Without it they may never see your reply.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Right :) Thanks for all your little nudges in making me a better member! :)

Comment: @HenrikKragh - That's what we're here to do - improve the quality of the questions, answers, and behaviours. It's what makes this site so good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved... Was a Unity specific compilation problem. Changed Scripting backend from Mono to IL2CPP which not only made everything perform WAY better, but also removed this problem as described. So JIT compilations was to blame. Still not sure how such a stupid inclusion of a clumsy condition made my the thread perform way better than without it, but now it works. And I learned a ton by fixing it.